# Reference a function inside an IIFE

Tags: javascript, function, logic, closures, iife

I have the following logic:

```
var first_function = (function(d3, second_function) {
  function third_function(param1, param2) {
    /* do stuff here */
  }
})(d3, second_function);
```

Outside of an IIFE structure, to access the third function, I could normally do something like:

```
first_function.third_function(data1, data2);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Note that the IIFE does not return anything, and it executes immediately, so basically `first_function` is `undefined` ?

Comment: what is your IIFE returning?  You need to return an object which has third_function as a property, otherwise you will not be able to access it.

Comment: Also, you can't access `third_function` outside the IIFE, that's what the closure does, the inner function is not available in the outer scope, unless you return something to make it available. The real question becomes; why do you use an IIFE at all ?

Comment: Appreciate the insights, @adeneo. I'm mainly using the IIFE to get better acquainted with them and also to not pollute globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not returning it, so the function is just evaporating. You can do something like this:

```
var first_function = (function(d3, second_function) {
  function third_function(param1, param2) {
    /* do stuff here */
  }
  return third_function;
})(d3, second_function);
```

Then, you can access it like this:

```
first_function( paramForThirdFunc1,paramForThirdFunc2);
```

Comment: Trying this. Will report back ASAP.

Comment: @daveycroqet I made a mistake, check this again :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to access a property from an IIFE, you need to make that property available by returning an object

```
var first_function = (function(d3, second_function) {

  // this function is unavailable to the outer scope
  function third_function(param1, param2) {
  /* do stuff here */
  }

  // this object allows us to access part of the inner scope
  // by passing us a reference
  return {
    third_function: third_function
  }
}})(d3, second_function);
```

Interestingly enough, we can also take advantage of this to create 'private' methods and variables.

```
var first_function = (function(d3, second_function) {

  // this function is unavailable to the outer scope
  function third_function(param1, param2) {
  /* do stuff here */
  }

  var myPrivate = 0; // outer scope cannot access

  // this object allows us to access part of the inner scope
  // by passing us a reference
  return {
    third_function: third_function,
    getter: function() {
      return myPrivate;   // now it can, through the getter 
    }
  }
}})(d3, second_function);
```

If you want to learn more about how this works, I suggest you read up on JavaScript scopes and closures.

Comment: Yes this is what he wants for sure.

Comment: I wish I could give you both answer credit. Harshal was simply faster, although this is a more fully fleshed out answer and I thank you for it.